# Trying to system restore my machine (HP G72 Notebook) to factory condition

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-restore

My computer is a HP G72 Notebook PC with dual core.

- OS: Windows 7 Home Edition

I don't have the Admin id password and I am trying to do a factory reset.
When I restart the machine and hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>, I see the following options:

- F1 System Information
- F2 System Diagnostics
- F9 Boot Device Options
- F10 BIOS Setup
- F11 System Recovery
- F12 Network Boot
- ENTER - Continue Startup

When I click on <kbd>F11</kbd>, it continues the booting and just comes back to Windows. It doesn't do anything else. I would like to do a system restore to a factory condition (not preferred) or preferably using a Windows image I backed up before.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the built-in recovery doesn't work you have one, possibly two, options. The possible option depends on whether HP offers a Recovery Partition repair tool. If this tool exists it will be on the HP Support Website under downloads. If this tool doesn't exist, then your only option is to perform a reinstall of Windows, either by retrieving the Recovery Image media from HP if you don't have it, or by using the Windows 7 OEM key on the computer and a valid Windows 7 OEM install disk.

Comment: My recovery partition is fine. When I restart and click Esc, it takes me to the menu I showed above. When I click on F11, it comes back to Windows directly whereas previously it used to go to the System Recovery screen.

Comment: Then your bootloader is messed up.